# Mocking internal modules when using Sphinx Autodoc

Tags: python, python-sphinx

My python package has a module called settings.py which looks for a settings.ini file, and if one isn't found raises an Exception.

My package works fine but when I try and use Sphinx Autodoc it fails because it can't find a settings file.

What options do I have for getting around this? The ones I can think of are

1. Put a settings.ini file in one of the Sphinx directories so it can be read.
2. Somehow mock the internal settings module if possible. The settings module is unimportant so I don't care if there is no documentation for it to the suer

Has anyone run into a similar issue when trying to generate Sphinx documentation on packages that need external files and if so what is your solution?

Comment: Do you actually need to have that settings file just to *load* the module?

Comment: The way I programmed it yes, at the time I thought it would be simpler. The package is a command line application that writes a bunch of stuff to dbs and the settings tell it which dbs. Is this bad practice? I can see how it's causing me issues now

Comment: If the settings file is just for a command-line program, then the file shouldn't be loaded until the command is actually run.  You'll run into the same problem if anyone ever runs `pydoc` on your package.

Comment: Got it. If you are able to is there any examples of this pattern that I can look it? Perhaps an open source package. I can also accept this answer if you want to put it below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyramid has a command-line script [pserve](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/pscripts/pserve.html) which loads an `.ini` settings file.

To document this script, we use [autoprogram](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-autoprogram/) as follows:

```
.. autoprogram:: pyramid.scripts.pserve:PServeCommand.parser
    :prog: pserve
```

and in your `conf.py`:

```
extensions = [
...
    'sphinxcontrib.autoprogram',
...
]
```

It requires the use of [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) in your script.